# How to use serial.available() inside a void loop() during delay in an Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, delay, arduino-uno

I want to execute a function whenever I send a value through a serial monitor but when a void loop() executing delay function serial. available() function doesn't work, So if I send any values in serial monitor during a periiod of delay function serial.available won't work

```
#define red 9
#define yellow 8
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
}
void LightON() {
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
void LightOff() {
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
}
void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    LightON();
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        LightOff();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this so when ever I enter a value in serial monitor during a delay period of function Lighton() so Lightoff() is executed?

Comment: Even if you could, calling `LightOff` wouldn't stop `LightON`. Fundamentally the architecture you are using can't support what you want. You need `LightON` to monitor `Serial` during the pauses instead of using long `delay`s. Perhaps using [`millis`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) to monitor the passage of time.

Comment: Okay, if I monitor serial in LightON what if LightON is in delay so serial.monitor() won't work at delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LightON` will always take 3 seconds. To avoid this, things get more complicated. You can use a state machine to keep track of where the blink sequence is at any given time. This also has the benefit of allowing your code to do other things instead of busy-looping or waiting on `delay()`.

```
// This class represents the led state machine
class blinker {
    public:
    // Possible states
    enum {START, RED_ON, YELLOW_ON, RED_OFF, INACTIVE};

    // Constructor
    blinker(byte red_pin, byte yellow_pin, long timeout=1000) :
            red(red_pin), yellow(yellow_pin), timeout(timeout), state(INACTIVE) {
        pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
    }

    // Start the loop from the beginning
    void start() {
        stop();
        state = START;
    }
    // Stop the loop
    void stop() {
        digitalWrite(red, LOW);
        digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
        state = INACTIVE;
    }

    // Update
    void loop() {
        // Only change if started and time is up
        if (state != INACTIVE && timer_expired()) {
            switch (state) {
                // Starting over?
                case START:
                    state = RED_ON;
                    digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
                    break;
                // Red is on, turn yellow on
                case RED_ON:
                    state = YELLOW_ON;
                    digitalWrite(yellow,HIGH);
                    break;
                // Yellow is on, turn red off
                case YELLOW_ON:
                    state = RED_OFF;
                    digitalWrite(red,LOW);
                    break;
                // Red is off, start over
                case RED_OFF:
                    state = START;
            }
        }
    }    

    protected:
    byte red, yellow;
    long timeout;

    // Returns true when time is up. 
    // Also resets the timer    
    bool timer_expired() {
        if ((millis() - last_time) >= timeout) {
            last_time = millis();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

// Create the state machine
blinker blinky(9, 8);
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Start loop
    blinky.start();
}

void loop() {
    // Call this everytime
    blinky.loop();

    // Stop?
    if (Serial.available()) {  
        blinky.stop();
    }

    // Can do other stuff here
}
```

I just threw this together. You can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom delay function like so :

```
bool LedOn;

void MyDelay(int ms) {
   for(int i=0;i<ms;i++){
      if (Serial.available())
      {
        LightOff();
        LedOn = false;
        break;
      }
      delay(1);
   }
}

void LightON() {
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
    MyDelay(1000);
    if(! LedOn) return;
    digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
    MyDelay(1000);
    if(! LedOn) return;
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    MyDelay(1000);
}
void loop() {
  LedOn = true;
  LightON();
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    LightOff();
    LedOn = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: When I enter a value in serial monitor it keeps repeating the same function

Comment: Edited by putting a `break`

Comment: No, I checked it using break; but same thing happens

Comment: It keeps repeating Lightoff()

Comment: Let's try using a global variable LedOn, see edited.